# (android) How to check if account changed in facebook application then proceed logout

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

My goal is that on every activity start, check if facebook account changed in main facebook app, and if changed force proceed

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Here`s my login code (i`m not using sessions):

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                SharedPreferences set = getSharedPreferences("account_pref", 0);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = set.edit();
                                editor.putString("fb_logged", "true");
                                editor.putString("fb_user", object.getString("name"));
                                editor.commit();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is this code doing and what you think it should do?

Comment: what`s unclear? i want to keep my app update with facebook...
this means whenever user changes facebook account inside of android phone i want activity to update the current one (i mean changed) name, email and etc

and code doing exactly same but one way, it does not catch facebook session at first launch but only on login button clicked